# force printer page with paper size b4 using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to setting the paper size when click button print.I using  ie8 web browsers.Please tell me any solution for this my problem

Answer (score 0):

See CSS3 documentation for following CSS3 solution

Go with CSS3 and change the dimensions of your rendered web page:

```
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
     @page {
        margin: 3cm;
     }
 }

/* style sheet for "letter" printing */
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
@page {
       margin: 1in;
    }
}

/* A4 Landscape*/
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
}
```